# Application of Bolzano's theorem in polynomials with the $a_n$ coefficient opposite.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)=x^2+βx+γ$ and $g(x)=-x^2+βx+γ$, where $γ \neq 0$. If $ρ_1$ is a real root of $f$ and $ρ_2$ a real root of $g$ with $ρ_1<ρ_2$, show that $f(x)+2g(x)=0$ has at least one real root in the interval $(ρ_1,ρ_2)$.

**Attempt at solution** 
Let $h(x)=f(x)+2g(x)$. Then $h(ρ_1)=2g(ρ_1)$ and $h(ρ_2)=f(ρ_2)$. I want to use the [Bolzano's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) on $h$ to show the existence of a real root. However, 
$$h(ρ_1)h(ρ_2)=2g(ρ_1)f(ρ_2)<0$$
is a necessary condition in doing so, and I am stuck in proving the later. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I think you mean $h(\rho_1) = 2g(\rho_1)$

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sign of g($ρ_1$) and f($ρ_2$) from the given equations.
For example, from $f(ρ_1)=0$ you can figure out something for g($ρ_1$).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Got it. I set $f(ρ_1)=g(ρ_1)+2ρ_1^2$, and similarly for $ρ_2$. thanks